# Application Id based on build type

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-build-type

I need to change full application Id based on build type not adding a suffix after Id. I have tried to move applicationId inside each build type but Gradle uses the last one in the last build type by default. 
Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use gradle filter to ignore some build/flavor targets.
Check the following code:

```
variantFilter { variant ->
   def flavor = variant.flavors*.name
   def buildType = variant.buildType*.name

   // To check for a certain build type, use variant.buildType.name == "<buildType>"
   if ((flavor.contains("xyz") && buildType.contains("debug"))) {
       // Gradle ignores any variants that satisfy the conditions above.
       setIgnore(true)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this simple approach and it works well

```
android {

    ...
    
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        if (variant.name.contains("debug")) {
            variant.mergedFlavor.applicationId = "application.id.debug"
        } else {
            variant.mergedFlavor.applicationId = "application.id.release"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is giving me error that `Val cannot be reassigned`!

Answer (score 0):

In order to change your applicationId you need to change your **package** in the manifest and in all your directories

> 1. Go to top left corner of Android Studio where it says **Android**
> 2. Click on it and change it to **Project Files** as of Android Studio 3.3
> 3. Right next to the side of Project Files click on the gear and **Uncheck "Compact Directories"**
> 4. Open folders -> click on app -> src -> main -> java -> **your** -> **package** -> **name**
> 5. Now that you see individual folders, **right click** the parts that you want to change -> **Refactor** -> **Rename**

Then you can change you applicationId and package in your **AndroidManifest.xml**

Hope it helps

source:
[Change Application Id Official Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id)